# How can I see the year in the entries in install.log in Macs (/private/var/log install.log)?

Tags: console

I noticed that in some Macs, the entries in install.log don't display the year:

Such as:
Oct-10 04:49:55+00 localhost opendirectoryd[186]...

Is there any way to see the year?:
something like:

2018-10-10 04:49:55+00 localhost opendirectoryd[186]... (I manually added the year to this one)

Any help much welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. That information doesn't exist.

`/var/log/install.log` is a plain text file. What you see in Console is the entirety of what's present in the file -- if the year isn't there, it isn't there.